# Pass sub domain to route service provider in Laravel so it can then be used for multi tenancy

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, service-provider

I have not done much work with route service providers and there seems to have been some changes around Laravel 5.4.

Basically I wish to use the boot function in route service provider to retrieve the sub domain so I can then query the main database to then set the sub database config and reconnection. I understand this could be done through middleware, however wish to do it through service providers.

**Route**

```
    Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.prop.dev'], function() {
  Route::get('/login', function () {
      return 'login';
  });
});
```

I cant see any problems with the above and where I dump in the route service provider it dumps but if I make a function the function doesnt seem to run and I have not managed to retrieve the subdomain.

There seems to be a lot of information using

```
$router->
```

but have struggled to find information using

```
Route::
```

My route service provider attempt is as follows:

```
public function boot()
{

parent::boot();

  Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.]+');

    Route::bind('domain', function ($value) {
        $domain= Customer::whereSubdomain($value)->first();
        if ($domain) {

            return $domain;
        }
        throw new Exception('error message');
    });

}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the domain using

```
request()->route()->parameter('domain');
```

Comment: I dont think there is a request passed to the service provider?

Comment: The request helper grabs the current request wherever you are (except possibly a provider::register method). You can also grab it from `$this->app->request->route()->parameter('domain') in the provider i believe.